# how to find index of newline in a string when using StringIO.open?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to learn some elixir. I believe that I can write;

```
def handleContent(txt) do 
    {:ok, pid} = StringIO.open(txt)
    line = IO.read(pid, 100) 
end
```

This allows me to create several processes that can read from the string knowing the pid. Is it some way of reading only a line from the string txt via the pid and IO.read? (to the \n character).

Comment: Out of topic, but since you're learning Elixir I figured it's good for you to know: the Elixir convention is to use underscores in function names instead of `camelCase`. In your example, the function name would be `handle_content`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `IO` documentation states](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/IO.html#read/2) that you can supply either `:all`, `:line` or a non-negative integer as third argument, so this should do the trick:

```
IO.read(pid, :line)
```

Comment: thank you. I am unused to atoms and their uses, so that was a good informative answer.